# In spark, how to tackle function with multiple arguments, the data of arguments come from rdd generated from local files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, we have two files, a.txt and b.txt, we want to add the data of two files together. Maybe my case is not an addition, I only want to test how to tackle the function with multiple arguments in spark, the data of arguments come from rdd generated from local files.

we can add a number to data of one file, such as codes:

```
a_data = sc.textFile("a.txt")
a_data.map(lambda x: x + 5)
```

How to add data of two files together with spark RDD?

Comment: Do you want to add the values of two RDD[Int]/RDD[Double] together into a single RDD?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe my description is not clear. I revise the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you want. If you want to add each element of RDD a to the corresponding element of RDD b, you can do it with zipWithIndex that will associate an ordered index to each element of each RDD (see [the scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD))

```
val a = sc.textFile("a.txt").zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
val b = sc.textFile("b.txt").zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)
a.fullOuterJoin(b)
 .map{ case(k, (v_a, v_b)) => v_a.getOrElse(0) + v_b.getOrElse(0) }
```

This code does not assumes the two files to have the same length (Zeros are added at the end in case they do not). If you assume that they have the same length, you can simply write:

```
a.join(b).map(_._2).map(_+_)
```